# Cannot remove item from nested list using recursion in Python

Tags: python, arrays, recursion

As the title states.  I am trying to iterate through a list using recursion and remove any number in the list (including nested lists) that is equal to a given number.  Here is what I have so far:

```
def deepRemoveAll(e, L):
    if len(L) == 0:
        return L
    if type(L[0]) == type([]):
        return deepRemoveAll(e, L[0])
    if e == L[0]:
        L.pop(0)
        return deepRemoveAll(e, L)
    if e != L[0]:
        temp = L[0]
        L.pop(0)
        return [temp] + deepRemoveAll(e, L)

print(deepRemoveAll(47, [42, 47, [1, 2, [47, 48, 49], 50, 47, 51], 52]))
```

The code seems flawless to me but for some reason the function is returning the list [42, 1, 2, 48, 49].  This is incorrect because in this case, all I need to remove are any 47's contained within but it is also removing 50, 51, and 52.  The nested lists also need to stay intact but this is combining everything into one and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Comment: Don't forget that in python you don't need semicolons :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at these two lines:

```
if type(L[0]) == type([]):
    return deepRemoveAll(e, L[0]);
```

What you are saying here is:

If the first element of the list is a list, then recurse on that list and **throw away** the rest of the elements of this list.

For example, if you had `L=[[1,2],3]`, your `if type(L[0]) == type([])` check would return true, and you would say `deepRemoveAll(e, [1,2])`, and the 3 is gone, regardless of what `e` is.

#### To fix your code:

Simply change `return deepRemoveAll(e, L[0]);` to `L[0] = deepRemoveAll(e, L[0])`, so that the first element of the list gets turned into itself with all the 47's removed, and then continue on with the rest of the logic.

Comment: But once it's done recursing through the list (L[0]) wouldn't it go back to the rest of the list after it finished with this particular one?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I read your if's as elif's.  My bad! Let me look again

Comment: No, @ChristopherShroba is right. You're doing a `return`. There's no "go back" involved. You are replacing [[1,2], 3] with [1,2]. In your `e != L[0]` branch you store away the L0 and recurse on the remainder of the list. You need to do something similar with the sublist.

Comment: @Heyya edited my answer with an easy fix to your code :)

Comment: @ChristopherShroba doyy how could I miss something so trivial haha.  Thanks for helping me see the light guys I appreciate it.  I see exactly what I did wrong now

Answer (score 3):

This should help:

```
def deep_remove_all(e, a_list):
    res = []
    for item in a_list:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            res.append(deep_remove_all(e, item))
        elif item != e:
            res.append(item)
    return res
```

You could also write it like this:

```
def deep_remove_all(e, a_list):
    res = []
    for item in a_list:
        if item == e:
            continue

        res.append( 
            deep_remove_all(e, item)
            if isinstance(item, list) 
            else item
        )

    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your code and find some stuff to fix:

```
def deepRemoveAll(e, L):
    if len(L) == 0:
            return L;
    if type(L[0]) == type([]):
            return deepRemoveAll(e, L[0]);
    if e == L[0]:
            L.pop(0);
            return deepRemoveAll(e, L);
    if e != L[0]:
            temp = L[0];
            L.pop(0);
            return [temp] + deepRemoveAll(e, L);

print(deepRemoveAll(47, [42, 47, [1, 2, [47, 48, 49], 50, 47, 51], 52]));
```

The first thing I see is just a quibble: `type([])`. In modern Python, that's `list`.

But before we change that, I notice you're doing a lot with `L[0]`, and you almost always `pop` it. Let's make that common:

```
def deepRemoveAll(e, L):
    if len(L) == 0: return L

    l0 = L.pop(0)
```

Now we've got l0 (so not more repeated indexing) and it's out. We can put it back, or not, as we decide.

```
if type(l0) == list:
```

That will fix the `type([])` above. But what do we do if the first element is a sublist? Obviously, we replace the first element with a deep-cleaned version of the first element:

```
if type(l0) == list:
    l0 = deepRemoveAll(e, l0)
```

It's still going to be the first element, but now we know it's clean.

Your next steps are to check if l0 is the `e` we want to remove. If so, you **don't** replace the start of the list - you just return cleaned-up remainder. That's correct, and it's also mutually exclusive with being a sub-list, so we can use an `else` or `elif`:

```
elif l0 == e:
    return deepRemoveAll(e, L)
```

And finally, there's the case where `l0 != e`. In this case, we want to clean the rest of L, and stick the l0 value back at the front.

*But wait!* That's also what we want to do in the case where l0 was a list, remember? All we did so far is clean up l0.

So let's fall out of the if/elif, so that we can merge the top code (l0 is a list) with the `else` code that we haven't put in: l0 != e.

```
return [l0] + deepRemoveAll(e, L)
```

Wrap it all up:

```
def deepRemoveAll(e, L):
    if len(L) == 0: return L

    l0 = L.pop(0)

    if type(l0) == list:
        l0 = deepRemoveAll(e, l0)
    elif l0 == e:
        return deepRemoveAll(e, L)

    return [l0] + deepRemoveAll(e, L)
```